# What Causes duplicate rows to appear in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I'm running a (very long) query, and there are a ton of duplicate rows. What clause causes this, and what would fix it?

I've already tried putting a `Distinct`on one of the columns in the select clause.

```
    Select Distinct location
        ,item_no
        ,order_no
    from (select *
          from stockA a
          join r_except re using (item_no)
          where re.location = 'locationA'

          UNION

          select * 
          from stockB b
          join r_except re using (item_no) 
          where re.location = 'locationB'
          ) ss

    left join r_except re 
    on ss.item_no = re.item_no

    left join (select ih.invoice_no
                    ,iih.item_no
                    ,sum(shipped * case) tot_shipped
               from invoice_hist ih inner join invoice_item_hist iih
                           on ih.invoice_no = iih.invoice_no
               where ih.invoice_date between (date 'now' - interval '12 months') and date 'now'
                       group by ih.invoice_no, iih.item_no) as ihsum
               on (ss.item_no = ihsum.item_no)


   join (select us.uitem
                  ,sum(ss.on_hand) uoh
                  ,sum(ss.vendor_order) vendor_order
                  ,max(case when ss.last_sale_date = '12/31/9999' then null else ss.last_sale_date end) last_sale_date                        
                  ,max(re.level) r_level
         from () ss inner join universal_no us
         on (ss.uitem = uoh.uitem)

left join (select ss.uitem
                    ,max(po.order_no) order_no
                    ,max(po.order_date) order_date
         from () ss inner join poitem poi
                                on ss.item_no = poi.item_no
                    inner join po
                          on po.order_no = poi.order_no
                    where poi.release_qty != poi.case_qty * poi.order_qty
                    group by ss.uitem
         ) po
         on ss.uitem = po.uitem
```

This is abridged, some of it may not be in the select clause, but that is because it would be too long.

Comment: You probably don't understand the cardinality of the relationships involved. Or you're not asking the database the correct question. Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish and without knowing anything about your schema, it's impossible to answer the question. If you show us the schema and the query. Sample data and expected/actual results are also helpful.

Comment: Alright, like I said, the query is very long, like 2000 lines of code, so I didn't want to flood it without know what caused the duplicates.

Comment: If you at least post the from clause we may be able to give you some idea where it went wrong.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to simplify it. Even that is around 500 lines.

Comment: I can add the rest of the select clause if you'd like

Comment: Maybe codereview.SE, but not SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two things you can look at are:

Are you joining tables with one to many relationships? This will often result in the same rows being returned multiple times. If there are multiple child rows connected to a parent.

The other more obvious reason could be that you actually have duplicate data in your database.